# Lua string to int

Tags: lua

How can I convert a string to an integer in Lua?

I have a string like this:

```
a = "10"
```

I would like it to be converted to 10, the number.

Comment: The precise link is the section on coercion: [5.1](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.2.1), [5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.2).

Comment: Lua just does automatically conversion between strings and numbers. If you want ensure the type, use a = tonumber(a).

Comment: Lua is dynamically typed, however if you have a use for it you can always do `tonumber()`

Answer (score 395, accepted):

Use the [`tonumber` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-tonumber). As in `a = tonumber("10")`.

Comment: In Lua 5.3, (64-bit default) integers are treated accordingly (http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html): "A numeric constant with a fractional dot or an exponent denotes a float; otherwise it denotes an integer."

Answer (score 42):

You can force an implicit conversion by using a string in an arithmetic operations as in `a= "10" + 0`, but this is not quite as clear or as clean as using `tonumber` explicitly.

Comment: Nope, it'll convert "10" to integer and then add 0 to it. (The lack of clarity is all the more reason to use `tonumber` instead, though!)

Comment: @Rena, there's no lack in clarity. `+` is always explicitly addition, `..` - concatenation.

Comment: @lhf: auto coercion will only work on numbers. And comparison operators (== ~= < > <= >=) do not convert their arguments. And for performance reasons you should avoid relying on automatic coercion too much

Answer (score 13):

All numbers in Lua are floats (**edit:** Lua 5.2 or less). If you truly want to convert to an "int" (or at least replicate this behavior), you can do this:

```
local function ToInteger(number)
    return math.floor(tonumber(number) or error("Could not cast '" .. tostring(number) .. "' to number.'"))
end
```

In which case you explicitly convert the string (or really, whatever it is) into a number, and then truncate the number like an (int) cast would do in Java.

**Edit:** This still works in Lua 5.3, even thought Lua 5.3 has real integers, as `math.floor()` returns an integer, whereas an operator such as `number // 1` will still return a float if `number` is a float.

Answer (score 11):

```
local a = "10"
print(type(a))
local num = tonumber(a)
print(type(num))
```

**Output**

```
   string                                                                                                                                                                          
   number
```

Answer (score 7):

[`tonumber (e [, base])`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-tonumber)

`tonumber` takes two arguments, first is string which is converted to number and second is base of `e`.

Return value `tonumber` is in base 10.

If no `base` is provided it converts number to base 10.

```
> a = '101'
> tonumber(a)
101
```

If base is provided, it converts it to the given base.

```
> a = '101'
> 
> tonumber(a, 2)
5
> tonumber(a, 8)
65
> tonumber(a, 10)
101
> tonumber(a, 16)
257
>
```

If `e` contains invalid character then it returns `nil`.

```
> --[[ Failed because base 2 numbers consist (0 and 1) --]]
> a = '112'
> tonumber(a, 2)
nil
> 
> --[[ similar to above one, this failed because --]]
> --[[ base 8 consist (0 - 7) --]]
> --[[ base 10 consist (0 - 9) --]]
> a = 'AB'
> tonumber(a, 8)
nil
> tonumber(a, 10)
nil
> tonumber(a, 16)
171
```

I answered considering Lua5.3

Answer (score 5):

say the string you want to turn into a number is in the variable `S`

```
a=tonumber(S)
```

provided that there are numbers and only numbers in `S` it will return a number,
but if there are any characters that are not numbers (except periods for floats)
it will return nil

Answer (score 5):

The clearer option is to use **tonumber**.

As of 5.3.2, this function will automatically detect (signed) integers, float (if a point is present) and hexadecimal (both integers and floats, if the string starts by "0x" or "0X").

The following snippets are shorter but not equivalent :

- ```
  a + 0 -- forces the conversion into float, due to how + works.
  ```
- ```
  a | 0 -- (| is the bitwise or) forces the conversion into integer. 
  -- However, unlike `math.tointeger`, it errors if it fails.
  ```

Answer (score 5):

It should be noted that `math.floor()` always rounds down, and therefore does not yield a sensible result for negative floating point values.

For example, -10.4 represented as an integer would usually be either truncated or rounded to -10. Yet the result of math.floor() is not the same:

```
math.floor(-10.4) => -11
```

For truncation with type conversion, the following helper function will work:

```
function tointeger( x )
    num = tonumber( x )
    return num < 0 and math.ceil( num ) or math.floor( num )
end
```

Reference: http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/5-3-Converting-a-floating-point-number-to-integer-td7664081.html

Answer (score 4):

Since lua 5.3 there is a new `math.tointeger` function for string to integer. Just for integer, no float.

For example:

```lua
print(math.tointeger("10.1")) -- nil
print(math.tointeger("10")) -- 10
```

If you want to convert integer and float, the `tonumber` function is more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I would recomend to check Hyperpolyglot, has an awesome comparison: http://hyperpolyglot.org/

http://hyperpolyglot.org/more#str-to-num-note

ps. Actually Lua converts into doubles not into ints.

> The number type represents real (double-precision floating-point)
>   numbers.

http://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make an accessor to keep the "10" as int 10 in it.

Example:

```
x = tonumber("10")
```

if you print the x variable, it will output an int 10 and not "10"

same like Python process

x = int("10")

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Lua digital types are **double precision types**, which are implemented in **luaconf. h** in detail
There are two general options:

1. **[Recommended use]** The Lua script in **version 5.3** contains the global.lua file, which includes the `tonumber()` and `tostring()` methods, which can realize the conversion of numbers and strings.
2. `math.tointeger()` It can also be converted into numbers by using this method.

However, according to your **actual scene**, if it is only for calculation, Lua can be converted according to this operation symbol. eg

```lua
  s = "1" + 2; -- lua will convert "1" to 1
  print(s)

  s1 = "e" + 3; -- error
  print(s1)
```

more about lua,you can see [lua official document](https://www.lua.org/docs.html)

Hope to be useful to you and look forward to your reply,and looking forward to further communication with you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tonumber()` to convert the string to a number, can be a float or an int.

Ex: `tonumber("11") -- return: 11`

Answer (score 1):

```
Lua 5.3.1  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> math.floor("10");
10
> tonumber("10");
10
> "10" + 0;
10.0
> "10" | 0;
10
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what you should put

```
local stringnumber = "10"
local a = tonumber(stringnumber)
print(a + 10)

output:

20
```

Comment: a = tonumber(stringnumber) is sufficent

Answer (score 0):

##### You can use **tonumber()** function as COMMON METHOD:

```
str = "234"
num = tonumber(str)
print(type(num))
print(num)
```

*BUT* you can use another UNCOMMON method:

```
str = "234"

num = str + 0

print(type(num))
```

###### Output:

```
number
```

Comment: Both of these were already answered.